# XLConnect interpreting a a user generated function as a name that is cant find

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

i am running in R XLConnect and want to invoke a user made formula and not a native XL formula.

```
form=paste('"gdp.q_n"','"2006"','"2014"',0,'"Quarterly"',sep=",")
form=paste("FAMEDate(",form,")",sep="")
setCellFormula(object=wb,sheet=sht,row=2,col=2,formula=form)
>Error: FormulaParseException (Java): Name 'FAMEData' is completely
 unknown in the current workbook
```

If i write it in the workbook and call it in getCellFormula then it returns the same formula in the object form but with a prefix of "!", i.e.

```
paste("!",form)
```

when i try to put that in the setCellFormula it returns a different error

```
>Error: FormulaParseException (Java): Parse error near char 0 '!'
 in specified formula. Expected cell ref or constant literal
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps misplace the second quote mark?

form=paste("FAMEDate(",form,")",sep="")

form=paste("FAMEDate", form, etc.

Comment: from xlconnect: Unfortunately user-made formulas are not currently supported by XLConnect since they are not supported by the underlying library Apache POI.
A note on the Apache documentation says:

Note that user-defined functions are not supported, and is not likely to be done any time soon... 

I am afraid that XLConnect will not support user-defined function until Apache POI will.

Thank you for  writing us and for your interest in XLConnect.
Please, do not hesitate to contact us if you have any other question.